# How do I change the label font size using Matplotlib, Tinker, and SubplotHost?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

Note that I am making a plot with nested axis labels. No matter what I try, the font size stays the same. Ideally, I would like to be able to give each set of axis labels their own color and font sizes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.parasite_axes import SubplotHost

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = SubplotHost(fig1, 111)
fig1.add_subplot(ax1)

# Some data
x = np.arange(1,6)
y = np.random.random(len(x))

# First X-axis
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_xticks(x)
ax1.set_xticklabels(['7up', 'cream', 'coke', 'rootb', 'cherryc'])
#ax1.xaxis.set_label_text('First X-axis') # Uncomment to label axis
ax1.yaxis.set_label_text("Sample data")

# Second X-axis
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
offset = 0, -25 # Position of the second axis
new_axisline = ax2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
ax2.axis["bottom"] = new_axisline(loc="bottom", axes=ax2, offset=offset)
ax2.axis["top"].set_visible(False)

ax2.set_xticks([0.0, 0.6, 1.0])
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0.3, 0.8]))
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(['weekly', 'daily']))

# Third X-axis
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
offset = 0, -50
new_axisline = ax3.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
ax3.axis["bottom"] = new_axisline(loc="bottom", axes=ax3, offset=offset)
ax3.axis["top"].set_visible(False)

ax3.set_xticks([0.0, 1.0])
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0.5]))
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(['customer favs']))

plt.show()
```

[image: figure output]

Comment: Try to change your axis color in this way: set different value of `matplotlib.rcParams['text.color']` before assignment of each axis. If you do it, you'll see that your `ax1` is a little bit complex unlike another two: it contains both `xaxis` and `yaxis`. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an individual setting, but it's all configurable in 'xticks.labelsize'. They are: 'xx-small, x-small, small, medium, medium, large, x-large and xx-large,'

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 'XX-large'
```

[image]